# How to make a toggle switch with enums

Tags: ios, swift, function, enums, toggle

I am looking into making a toggle switch for the camera input. What I am aiming at is having an enum that I can call like `CameraPosition.rear` or `CameraPosition.front` and the camera input changes accordingly. 
This is what I got so far:

```
    var currentCameraPosition: CameraPosition?
    var frontCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var rearCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
    var currentCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

enum CameraPosition {
        case front
        case rear

    func toggle(){
        switch self {
        case .front:
            currentCameraInput = frontCameraInput
        case .rear:
            currentCameraInput = rearCameraInput
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that my compiler complains `Instance member 'currentCameraInput' cannot be used on type 'Camera'`. How should I fix this, or how can I rewrite it?

Comment: Wouldn’t a boolean value that indicates if the camera is to front or not be easier?

Comment: What is type `Camera`? Is that a type you defined, or some system type I'm not aware of?

Comment: Duncan, that's my class where I'm using the enums

Comment: J. Doe, it  would, yes. I just want to see if there's any way I can do it with emuns

Comment: There's no problem with using an enum if you want, but the error is from something else that we're not seeing in your limited code sample.

Comment: @dre_84w934 When you reply to a user, please precede their username with the `@` symbol. Without that the user will likely not be notified of your reply.

Comment: @rmaddy didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally use an enum for this if you like.  I'd recommend using `didSet` to toggle rather than having to set your `CameraPosition` and then separately call `toggle`.  This way, setting your camera position will automatically update your camera input.  I'd set it up like this:

```
var currentCameraPosition: CameraPosition? {
  didSet {
    if let position = currentCameraPosition {
      switch position {
        case .front: currentCameraInput = frontCameraInput
        case .rear: currentCameraInput = rearCameraInput
      }
    }
  }
}
var frontCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var rearCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?
var currentCameraInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput?

enum CameraPosition {
    case front
    case rear
}
```

You could even ditch the switch and use a ternary operator since you only have 2 options:

```
var currentCameraPosition: CameraPosition? {
  didSet {
    if let position = currentCameraPosition {
      currentCameraInput = position == .front ? frontCameraInput : rearCameraInput
    }
  }
}
```